# Looping thorough an array to make axios calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I'm making an API call to get all the devices connected to my local server. I'm then trying to loop through all the devices connected and make more calls to get some data. How would I loop through all the devices and not just the first one in the array?

Here is the response i'm storing in the devices variable

> [{"connected":true,"functions":["SetGain","SetIntegTime","SetInterrupt","Enable","begin"],"id":"1f0039000547363339343638","last_app":null,"last_heard":"2018-10-26T16:01:34.974Z","last_ip_address":"::ffff:10.10.10.5","name":"actually-jail","platform_id":6,"product_firmware_version":65535,"product_id":6,"status":"normal","variables":{"RawData":"string","ColorTemp":"string","Lux":"string","SensorArray":"string","Gain":"string","IntegraTime":"string","TemperatureC":"double","TemperatureF":"double","TemperatureK":"double","TemperatureR":"double"}},{"connected":false,"functions":null,"id":"3a003a001047363333343437","last_app":null,"status":"normal","variables":null}]

```
async function getDevices() {
      let devices = await  axios('http://10.10.10.1:8080/v1/devices/?access_token=687b5aee0b82f653c725570422dea5d37de6b65f')
      return this.devices = (devices.data[0].id)};


async function getVariables() {

  try {
    const devices = await getDevices();
    console.log(devices);
    const RawDataPromise = axios(API + devices + '/RawData/?access_token=' + Token);
    const ColorTempPromise = axios(API + devices + '/ColorTemp/?access_token=' + Token);
    const LuxPromise = axios(API + devices + '/Lux/?access_token=' + Token);
    const SensorArrayPromise = axios(API + devices + '/SensorArray/?access_token=' + Token);
    const GainPromise = axios(API + devices + '/Gain/?access_token=' + Token);
    const IntegraTimePromise = axios(API + devices + '/IntegraTime/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureCPromise = axios(API + devices + '/TemperatureC/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureFPromise = axios(API + devices + '/TemperatureF/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureKPromise = axios(API + devices + '/TemperatureK/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureRPromise = axios(API + devices + '/TemperatureR/?access_token=' + Token);
    const [RawData, ColorTemp, Lux, SensorArray, Gain, IntegraTime, TemperatureC, TemperatureF, TemperatureK, TemperatureR] = await Promise.all([RawDataPromise, ColorTempPromise, LuxPromise, SensorArrayPromise,GainPromise,IntegraTimePromise,TemperatureCPromise,TemperatureFPromise,TemperatureKPromise,TemperatureRPromise]);
    console.log(RawData.data.result, ColorTemp.data.result,Lux.data.result,SensorArray.data.result,Gain.data.result,IntegraTime.data.result,TemperatureC.data.result,TemperatureF.data.result,TemperatureK.data.result,TemperatureR.data.result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
getVariables();
```

Comment: It looks like you're using `Promise.all` right, what sort of results are you getting right now? Also, just a suggestion, to keep things DRY, you might put `API + devices` and `'?access_token=' + Token` into a variable

Comment: Im able to get the first device out of the array because I hard coded   ~return this.devices = (devices.data[0].id)};~ but I want to make calls for all the devices in the array not just the first entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper function for getting the values from a single device, then call this multiple times using Promise.all (or Promise.map/each if using bluebird);

```
async function getDevices() {
  let devices = await  axios('http://10.10.10.1:8080/v1/devices/?access_token=687b5aee0b82f653c725570422dea5d37de6b65f');

  return this.devices = (devices.data)
};

async function getForOneDevice(device) {
    // I've assumed here that 'devices' in your API calls was a typo, and was intended to be devices[0] (based on the question)
    const RawDataPromise = axios(API + device + '/RawData/?access_token=' + Token);
    const ColorTempPromise = axios(API + device + '/ColorTemp/?access_token=' + Token);
    const LuxPromise = axios(API + device + '/Lux/?access_token=' + Token);
    const SensorArrayPromise = axios(API + device + '/SensorArray/?access_token=' + Token);
    const GainPromise = axios(API + devices + '/Gain/?access_token=' + Token);
    const IntegraTimePromise = axios(API + device + '/IntegraTime/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureCPromise = axios(API + device + '/TemperatureC/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureFPromise = axios(API + device + '/TemperatureF/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureKPromise = axios(API + device + '/TemperatureK/?access_token=' + Token);
    const TemperatureRPromise = axios(API + device + '/TemperatureR/?access_token=' + Token);
    return Promise.all([RawDataPromise, ColorTempPromise, LuxPromise, SensorArrayPromise,GainPromise,IntegraTimePromise,TemperatureCPromise,TemperatureFPromise,TemperatureKPromise,TemperatureRPromise]);
}

async function getVariables() {
    try {
        const devices = await getDevices();
        console.log(devices);

        const promises = [];
        devices.forEach((device) => {
            promises.push(getForOneDevice(device.id));
        })

        const allResults = Promise.all(promises);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}

getVariables();
```

Comment: It't hitting an error on `devices.forEach((device) => {
            promises.push(getForOneDevice(device.id));
        })`    I added the response that gets stored in the devices variable

Comment: What's the error? I've been typing up the code on my mobile, so likely made some typos

Comment: One of my photons didn't have the proper firmware installed so it wasn't  connecting. Everything works as it should now thanks!!